# Injecting WHERE clause into pgpromise pg SELECT query

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

I'd like to be able to reuse a `SELECT` query by injecting a conditional `WHERE` clause. See example below.

```
let where = null;
if(condition) where = `WHERE patient.mongodb_id = $2`;

const patient = await db
.oneOrNone(
  `SELECT * FROM patients
   $1:value;`,
  [where, mongodbId]
```

I'm aware that the code above is wrong as it throws the following error: `error: there is no parameter $2`. I've read through the docs and I don't seem to be able to find a good example on how to do this.

Comment: Probably `where = format('WHERE patient.mongodb_id = $1', [mongodbId])`

Comment: You put me in the right direction, thank you!!